# How do I set a child value of a Firebase Realtime Database when using a ViewModel and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have the following `data class` that holds the child values of a specific reference from the Firebase Realtime Database:

```
data class Users(
    val uid: String = "",
    var firstName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = "",
)
```

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
class UsersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
    private val USERS_REF: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
    private val liveData: FirebaseQueryLiveData = FirebaseQueryLiveData(USERS_REF)
    private val usersLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Users> = MediatorLiveData()

    init {
        usersLiveData.addSource(liveData, object : Observer<DataSnapshot> {
            override fun onChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                    usersLiveData.postValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java))
                } else {
                    usersLiveData.value = null
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @NonNull
    fun getUsersLiveData() : LiveData<Users> {
        return usersLiveData
    }
}
```

This is my extended `LiveData`:

```
class FirebaseQueryLiveData(ref: DatabaseReference) : LiveData<DataSnapshot>() {
    private val query: Query = ref
    private val listener: MyValueEventListener = MyValueEventListener()
    private var listenerRemovePending = false

    private val removeListener = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            query.removeEventListener(listener)
            listenerRemovePending = false
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).removeCallbacks(removeListener)
        } else {
            query.addValueEventListener(listener)
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(removeListener, 2000)
        query.removeEventListener(listener)
    }

    private inner class MyValueEventListener : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            value = snapshot
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

For reading the values from my database in my `Activity` or `Fragment`, this is what I've done:

```
val usersViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UsersViewModel::class.java)
val usersLiveData = usersViewModel.getUsersLiveData()
usersLiveData.observe(this, object : Observer<Users> {
    override fun onChanged(users: Users?) {
        if (users != null) {
            firstNameTextView.text = users.firstName
            lastNameTextView.text = users.lastName
        }
    }
})
```

This all works, but my question is how do I write to a specific child for my database in my `Activity` or `Fragment`? For example, let's say I want to only modify the `lastName` child? How do I do that? I don't have any references to `FirebaseDatabase` in my activities and fragments because the `ViewModel` and `LiveData` ensure that I don't need them anymore.

Comment: You can pass the `lastName` from your Activity to your ViewModel after creating a new function with the logic to update the database, which in this case, is Firebase.  Just like `getUsersData`, you can make a new function say `setLastName`, you definitely have the `DatabaseReference` in your ViewModel, don't you?

Comment: And as far as I know, Firebase won't support editing the `lastName` directly, you will have to pass a new `User` or whatever your model is with the updated property value to Firebase and then it will update it accordingly

Comment: What have you tried so far in code for writing the data to the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Prior to using a `ViewModel` and `LiveData`, I would write the data like this: `Firebase.database.getReference("users").child(auth.currentUser!!.uid).child("lastName").setValue(newValue)`. Not sure how writing data to the database would work now with no reference to the database in my activities and fragments.

Comment: @gtxtreme Yes, I have `DatabaseReference` in my `ViewModel` as you can see it's used in the primary constructor.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(newValue)` operation to see if something's wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo How would I do that? The only place where I have a listener is in my extended `LiveData`. So not exactly sure on how to go about adding another listener to my activity/fragment.

Comment: .setValue(newValue).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*); Try this.

Comment: @TomDarious: to detect errors when writing, see https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But this requires me to create a `DatabaseReference` inside my activity/fragment. Is there a way to write to a database with what I currently have that doesn't require me to create a `DatabaseReference`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Isn't a listener only required when reading values? Why would I need to create another listener when I'm just writing to the database?

Comment: A listener is required in both cases. When reading data and when writing data. When you read data you need to know when the returned documents are downloaded and when writing data, you need to know when the operation finishes. In both cases, you need to check if the you get an error.